# Замена фнукции session_is_registered

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. В древнем движке ShopScript ругается на устаревшую функцию

```
if(!session_is_registered($this->SPrefix.'IVAL'))return false;
```

Заменяю её следующем образом

```
if(isset($_SESSION['this'])->SPrefix.'IVAL'))return false;
```

Но всё равно ругается, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так должно работать:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION[$this->SPrefix.'IVAL'])) return false;
```

То, что вы написали вообще работать не должно.